# Elementary tweak with Pantheon in Lubuntu

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, ubuntu-tweak, elementary

I have installed elementary-desktop on my Lubuntu in VMWare. 
Now I wanted to install the numix circle icon pack and hence was trying to install Elementary tweak tools. I
 have added the versable/elementary-tweak-isis repositoryusing :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:versable/elementary-tweak-isis
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But whatevet I do it always says

```
unable to locate package elementary-tweaks
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this repository: [ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily](https://launchpad.net/elementary-tweaks)

Type in the terminal:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks`

I had the same issue and this worked for me on the first try.

Comment: Use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks` if the above doesn't work since it's outdated and not maintained anymore.